# How to best power small loads from 1.5V batteries in a kit?

Tags: step-up, through-hole

I'm trying to build an electronics kit (so THT parts only if possible) that I would like to power from a single AA battery.  The circuitry on the kit uses 3.3V 74HC series CMOS parts and should consume less than 100 mA peak current.

What's a good part/circuit to use for powering this kit?  I've found the [MAX 856](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/switching-regulators/MAX856.html) part which seems like it's ideal for this application, but it's expensive and the DIP version seems to be discontinued.

Comment: I think that you'll have a problem with the through-hole only bit.  Surface mount is pretty much taking over the world, and especially so with switchers, which really benefit from a smaller layout.  If you just can't bear to learn how to do surface mount, look around and see if there are modules to be bought.

Comment: @TimWescott I can deal with SMD parts just fine, but beginners who might try to build the kit won't be.

Comment: you may have to put some SMD FETs on 3 pin package with a heatsink although this adds inductance

Comment: You could pre-mount the SMD parts and leave the through-hole parts to be assembled by the user.  I've seen a lot of kits do this.

Comment: WRT to boost regulators, I rather like the [AP1603](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP1603.pdf) which boosts from as low as 0.9V (start-up voltage) to 3.3V (150mA), 5V (80mA), or adjustable voltages (the fixed voltages need no external components to set the voltage). The IC is a SOT-23-6 and needs minimal external components (3 caps, 1 inductor for fixed voltage, +2 resistors for variable).  Mouser, e.g., has it for US$0.68 @ 1, US$0.289 @ 1000.

Comment: @AlexHajnal - The AP1603 looks pretty good. However it only has a guaranteed minimum operating voltage of 1.1V. That's a bit high for running off a single AA cell.

Comment: A simple way to achieve a 3.3v supply from a single cell is to simply buy a tiny module from amazon.  Do a quick search for "1.5v to 3.3v step up", you'll find dozens of them, and for very reasonable prices.  With only 3 or 4 header pins you could mount a small module as if it was just another small component.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll probably want to implement a switcher with discrete bipolar transistors for both the switching element and for the control amplifier.

What are the loads besides the logic? Logic can run subthreshold from 1.5V directly, just low current and it’ll be much slower, so you’ll need output amplifier BJTs to drive LEDs and such.

For anything that is human-interactive, like some switches and gates/counters etc., that can run at a kHz or so, subthreshold operation may be well suited, since you don’t need MHz clock rates. Also the active current consumption from the logic (when switching) will be very low – well under 1mA.

What is the highest clock rate and the number of 74HC chips?

Comment: We have about six-ish chips plus the (two bus drivers, a counter, a 4-to-10 demultiplexer, two 555).  Output is a piezo or small speaker (this is a device for blind users) which will be the largest load.  The max switching rate is a few dozen kHz for one of the 555 (driving the speaker).  The other parts switch at at most 5 Hz.

Comment: To reduce power requirements even further try using a CMOS version of a 555 timer IC: LMC555. TLC555, or TS555.

Comment: @FUZxxl What are the bus-drivers for? This could be probably made to run entirely on 1.5V using 74HC. Timing can be done using 74HC too, 555 is not needed and is a power hog compared to CMOS 74HC. You should definitely try how 74HC runs from 1.5V for you. Just keep in mind that output currents are tiny: microamps to a fraction of mA. So even a 10M scope probe may be interfering too much with things. And if you need to drive any non-CMOS load, you need a Sziklai pair (a low-voltage Darlington equivalent). Use a FET op-amp like TL08x/TL07x as a buffer for feeding node voltages to scopes, etc.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The bus drivers are for measuring a resistor network (it's a network cable with a resistor network attached to the other end) by pulling one line up and the others low.  The device measures the current flowing through the bus driver which is mirrored to charge the 555's capacitor, producing a sound of pitch anti proportional to the total resistance.  The device is a cable tester.

Comment: @Nedd Yes, of course.  Will do that.